# How are sockets implemented in JVM?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, jvm

I want to know, how sockets are implemented in the Java Virtual Machine.

- Is there a native library included?
- And if, is it a C library?

Where can I find information about this topic?
The [offical Java tutorial on networking](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/TOC.html) does not help me there.

Some interesting links would help.

Update:
Are there any official information provided by Sun?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I found a proof, I mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks to Oscar, that was the perfect hint for me!!! THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [network guide of Java 1.4.2](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/socketOpt.html), an interesting piece of information is provided:

> **The implementation details...**
>
> ...that you don't need to know, unless you
>   subclass
>   SocketImpl/DatagramSocketImpl. **Every
>   *Socket object has an underlying SocketImpl/DatagramSocketImpl that
>   interfaces to native code.** The Impl
>   classes implement two methods to
>   support options:
>
> void setOption(int optID, Object val)
>   throws SocketException;   Object
>   getOption(int optID) throws
>   SocketException;
>
> that *look much like C*. These methods
>   act as glue to the native methods, and
>   ensure type safety before native
>   methods are invoked.

So I think it's proofed: Java uses native libraries for sockets.

Comment: Well, from the source I can tell that method is "native" thus uses a native library that could be either in C, C++ or assembly. As for the quote, documentation is not running software. :)  What is the rationale of your question anyway?

Comment: I need to compare network programming techniques in Linux and Windows of Java and Python.

Answer (score 5):

Probably using the system-V socket calls exposed by the underlying platform, e.g. system-V under Unix, WinSock under Windows. The specification only dictates how a virtual machine must behave, so implementers are free to do as they wish.

Answer (score 5):

Java is open source, so you can grab the source code for a self paced deep examination of the class.

As an start and quick answer to your question here's what I've found in a very quick scan:

```
private native void socketConnect(InetAddress address, int port, int timeout)
```

So yeap, a native lib is included and my guess it is a C++ library.

There are a number of implementations ( SSLSocket, PlainSocket etc. )

The online source of JDK7 is [here](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/net/Socket.java.html)  :S <sub>Not sure how up to date it is</sub>

I've used my IDE to navigate the source code that comes with every JDK installation.

[IDE screenshot showing the source of Socket http://img83.imageshack.us/img83/5358/socketimpfv3.png](http://img83.imageshack.us/img83/5358/socketimpfv3.png)

Comment: It's hard to mark this question as the answer, because I need an official citation o.s.e.  +1 of course